# Prove that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2), \mathbb Q(w\sqrt[3]2), \mathbb Q(w^2\sqrt[3]2)$ where $w = (-1+i\sqrt3)/2$ are distinct fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I know that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2), \mathbb Q(w\sqrt[3]2), \mathbb Q(w^2\sqrt[3]2)$ are isomorphic to each other.

However, I don't quite see how we can show that in fact they are distinct. The book only says that "they differ in that they contain different elements, but they are essentially the same except for the names of their elements".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, for starters, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, so that distinguishes the first field. On the other hand, can you show that the fields $\mathbb{Q}(\omega \sqrt[3]{2})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\omega^2 \sqrt[3]{2})$ aren't equal as sets? To do this, it would suffice to show that, say,

$$\omega \sqrt[3]{2} \notin \mathbb{Q}(\omega^2 \sqrt[3]{2})$$

Comment: Can we assume by the sake of contradiction that \omega \sqrt[3]{2}  ∈ \mathbb{Q}(\omega^2 \sqrt[3]{2})